# How do I infer generics from an extended interface?

Tags: typescript, interface, narrowing

I have an interface with a generic field, sort of like

```
interface HasVal<T> {
    val: T
}
```

I want to create a function like `get_val` which accepts any `HasVal` implementer and returns it's val:

```
function get_val<T, Hv extends HasVal<T>>(hv: Hv): T {
    return hv.val
}
```

This doesn't work, because T doesn't get narrowed for some reason:

```
class MyVal {
    val = "hello world!"
}

let u = get_val(new MyVal());
// type of u is unknown :(
```

Is there a type signature for `get_val` that will return the proper type without requiring the caller to specify it?

Comment: You don't need `Hv`, just `T`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nn5qqw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah that's right, totally forgot that interfaces don't have to be extended ^^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
declare function get_val<T, Hv extends HasVal<T>>(hv: Hv): T;
```

is that [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) are not used as inference sites for other [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments.  (Such a feature was suggested at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) but eventually declined in favor of other techniques.)  So while `Hv` can be inferred from the `hv` argument, `T` cannot be inferred from the `Hv extends HasVal<T>` constraint.  There's pretty much nowhere from which `T` can be inferred, so it falls back to the implicit `unknown` constraint, and you get the undesirable behavior.

---

Given this example, I'd be inclined to just remove the `Hv` type parameter entirely.  If you want to infer `T` from an input of type `HasVal<T>`, tell the compiler that `hv` is of type `HasVal<T>` directly, not indirectly via a constraint:

```
function get_val<T>(hv: HasVal<T>): T {
    return hv.val
}
```

And now things behave as desired:

```
let u = get_val(new MyVal());
// let u: string
```

`T` is inferred as `string` because a `MyVal` instance is seen as a valid `HasVal<string>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4DU4BsA8AKgHzIDeAsAFDK3IBueAXModQL7VdUK6YbIAsgE8cuctToM8yALzIARAAsIuXAHtkAd3VRcAEwCECjtxgBXEAjDB1IZAHMIYAPqMCJABRL6LdNjwiYgBKFkIJGjooZ3Moex8AOndTKlxnZHM5R2c3PE8QCC0hUTzg4IBuagB6KuQ0sAyWDDAoUAdqIA)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a generic that adheres to some interface that also has a generic, you can do this too:

```
interface Yeah<T> {
  val: T
}

function woo<T, U>(yeaher: T & Yeah<U>) {
  // ...
}
```